# IF logic only follows the Else condition

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have an if statement where only the else value is printed.

The values it selects are in five cells with numbers below 1 and above zero.

It should print one cell offset to the right the word "greater" if the number is greater than 0.5 or equal and smaller of the number is smaller than 0.5.

```
Sub checkifstatement()

    Dim result As String
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

    rngoff = rng.Offset(, 1)

    For Each c In rng
        If c.Value >= 0.5 Then
            rngoff = "greater"    
        Else    
            rngoff = "smaller"
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

If after the else I replace the code with:
`Range("B" & c.Row) = "smaller"`
it works.

Comment: Please some sample data and repro steps. Without seeing the data and knowing what you're doing it's not really possible to answer. Remember to use the [edit] link to add the information directly to the question.

Comment: Sorry. I'll edit it right now.

Comment: Also indent your code, otherwise it's impossible to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module/before your code.

---

Regarding this line:

```
rngoff = rng.Offset(, 1)
```

Since you haven't explicitly declared `rngoff`, `rngoff` is implicitly a `Variant` -- and is also implicitly being assigned whatever value<sup>1</sup> is in the range `rng.Offset(, 1)`.

This means if you assign something to `rngoff` (later in the loop), you're updating the value of the variable, but not the cell (immediately to the right of `rng`).

I think you wanted `rngoff` to be a `range` object. So you should replace:

```
rngoff = rng.Offset(, 1)
```

with:

```
Dim rngoff as Range
Set rngoff = rng.Offset(, 1)
```

When storing objects in a variable, the `Set` keyword is required.

And as pointed out by @RonRosenfeld, you will likely want `Set rngoff = c.Offset(, 1)` (or just `c.Offset(,1).Value = ...`) inside the `For Each` loop (meaning you don't need the `Set rngoff = rng.Offset(, 1)` before the loop).

<sup>1</sup> This happens since the default member of `Range` is `Range.Value`.

Comment: That's not the only problem.  If what you show are the only changes he makes, `rngoff` will be filled with whatever the result is for the last comparison in `rng`.  You need to also ensure that he fills `rngoff` one cell at a time, and not the entire range each time as is done by his code.